# How do you find out what country a file is hosted?

Tags: traceroute

I'm downloading a file from Adobe which appears to be coming from a local source but im not sure.

Local traffic is free which is why im trying to find out.
Download speed seems very slow to be local...

```
traceroute to 202.124.127.104 (202.124.127.104), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets 
1  citylink-wgtn.actrix.co.nz (203.96.59.1)  2.785 ms  2.601 ms  2.372 ms
2  202.49.152.197 (202.49.152.197)  3.154 ms  2.889 ms  3.134 ms
3  wn-cisco-r2-fa-0-0.connections.net.nz (202.49.152.218)  2.732 ms  2.510 ms  2.876 ms
4  snap.wix.net.nz (202.7.1.240)  3.546 ms  5.025 ms  3.664 ms
5  * * *
6  104.127.124.202.static.snap.net.nz (202.124.127.104)  18.275 ms  18.077 ms  19.211 ms
```

But what server is hop 5

Comment: What exactly is your provider's definition of "local"?

Comment: Anything that is hosted within the country, so New Zealand. Also I wonder how they detect if something is local or not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All that matters is the destination host IP.

Country: **New Zealand** (~ City: **Christchurch**)

See:
http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=202.124.127.104